# KDE Plasma 5 - adjust "dimmed" screen brightness

Tags: linux, laptop, display, kde, brightness

KDE 5 power management allows to enable screen dimming after some period of inactivity:

[image: power management]

I'm using 900 nit high brightness display in laptop but I usually work at night so my typical "full" brightness is set at around 10% of brightness supported by display (and it's already quite bright).

When I enable "Dim screen" option it actually increases brightness of my display after 10 minutes because "dimmed" screen for KDE is significantly above 10% of brightness so it doesn't make any sense.

Is there any way to set "dimmed" screen brightness in KDE 5 to 5% or below? Alternatively: is it possible to rescale/offset brightness scale? because currently i have realistically only 3 levels of brightness because level 0 disables screen at all and anything above 3 is burning my eyes.